# Pandas: How to replace values in a dataframe based on a conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace the values of my second dataframe ('area') with those of my first dataframe ('test').

Image of my inputs:

[image]

The catch is that I only want to replace the values that are not NaN, so, for example, area.iloc[0,1] will be "6643.68" rather than "3321.84" but area.iloc[-2,-1] will be "19.66" rather than "NaN". I would have thought I could do something like:

```
area.loc[test.notnull()] = test
```

or

```
area.replace(area.loc[test.notnull()], test.notnull())
```

But this gives me the error "Cannot index with multidimensional key". Any ideas? This should be simple.

Comment: This seems a case of using `.update()` rather than using `fillna()`.   Anyway, there is an answer in the link that marked this post dup.

Answer (score 0):

Use fillna like:

```
area.fillna(test)
```